# Understanding Client-Server connection

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm new to socket programming and I'm trying to make a server-client connection using gcc compiler in linux. Server and Client ,both codes are in different C files.I'm sending a character to a server through user input , server increments the character and return it to client.The client should remain in the connection until I get character 'Q' from the user.I'm having trouble in maintaining the connection. Here I'm pasting the client code.It works fine when I don't use while loop and sends only one character but what If I repeatedly want to send character over the same connection , and connection would only close when user enters the Q. Well, In the 1st iteration of loop It asks for character and successfully gets the incremented character from server but 2nd time It says "Transport endpoint is already connected". Kindly help me in understanding this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    int len, port;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int result;
    char ch;
    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    address.sin_port = port;
    len = sizeof(address);


    while (1){

        printf("Enter Character To Send The Server OR Q/q To End The  Connection:");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        fflush(stdin);

        if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len) == -1) {
            perror("oops: client failed to connect");
            return 1;
        }
        if (ch == 'Q' || ch == 'q'){
            printf("Connection Closed");
            break;
        }

        write(sockfd, &ch, 1);
        read(sockfd, &ch, 1);
        printf("Incremented character from server = %c\n", ch);

    } close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The message says it all: you're trying to `connect` an already connected socket (in your second and later iterations). In TCP, once a connection is established, it remains open until you manually shut it down. Simply move the `connect` call out of the `while` loop.

Comment: @szczurcio Yes I tried by putting the connection before the loop , In that case here is the output. The abnormal termination .
                                                                                                          Enter Character To Send The Server OR Q/q To End The Connection:A

Incremented character from server = B


Enter Character To Send The Server OR Q/q To End The 

Connection:Incremented character from server = 


                          Enter Character To Send The Server OR Q/q To End The Connection:K

 "Program Terminates

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly where you might be going wrong without you posting your subsequent edits.

Maybe you are closing the file descriptor accidentally due to the placement of your brackets (as part of the while loop block definition)?

You should only need to call *connect()* once in your case.
The following code works fine for me (my server code simply writes the character received by the client back to it and the client receives/prints it as expected).

I had to add:

```
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
```

Then move the *connect()* function call out of the while loop ensuring that the *close* function call was made only when breaking from the loop i.e. receiving *q* or *Q*.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int sockfd;
    int len, port;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int result;
    char ch;
    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    len = sizeof(address);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len) == -1) {
            perror("oops: client failed to connect");
            return 1;
        }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter Character To Send The Server OR Q/q To End The Connection:");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        fflush(stdin);

        if (ch == 'Q' || ch == 'q'){
            printf("Connection Closed");
            break;
        }

        write(sockfd, &ch, 1);
        read(sockfd, &ch, 1);
        printf("Incremented character from server = %c\n", ch);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

If you are still having problems, then maybe something strange is happening within your server code.  Are you accidentally disconnecting the client?

Some great, easy to understand examples here:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming